# Profiling the empty string in SSIS Data Profiling

Tags: sql-server, ssis, data-profiling

I've just started using the Data Profiling Task in SSIS to profile some data on our databases. I've found the option for profiling the column null ratios ("Column Null Ratio Profiles") but I'm interested in profiling for the empty string ("") as well as null values.

I've tried googling but not had any luck. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: What you're really asking about is the capability to define custom profiles. The answer to that question is 'No'. However, @Hadi has a great workaround in this related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51665819/data-profiling-task-custom-profile-request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've looked into this further and there is no built-in profile to achieve what I want.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/data-profiling-task?view=sql-server-2017 lists the profiles that you can use and there is no "profile the number of blank strings" profile to use.